# Invalid API Key provided: pk_live_ in React Form

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I am certain that I've tried everything.

I am building a NextJS app and using the

```
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
```

It is making a call at

```
https://api.stripe.com/v1/elements/sessions?
key=pk_live_51KpyLFB...jijj%7D
&type=setup_intent&locale=en-US&client_secret=seti_1NFl...wUL
&expand[0]=payment_method_preference.setup_intent.payment_method
```

the Stripe keys are correct. And I still get this error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid API Key provided: pk_live_************************************************************************************************ijj}",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

What on earth could be wrong??

Comment: What code generates this?

Comment: The curly brace at the end of that error code seems suspicious. Was that added by accident? I believe all Stripe keys are alphanumeric.

Comment: Sorry. I updated the question with more details

Comment: Yeah, I think it's still an issue with that curly brace. Do you still receive an error if you remove `%7D` before `&type`?

Comment: @LauraT I want you to send me an address so I can send you a bottle of champagne!!!! How did you spot it? I was looking at the same code with my devs for 3 hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the answer here so it's not nested in the comments. The issue here is the extra curly brace at the end of the public key. I believe Stripe's keys are alphanumeric and don't include symbols.

In the /elements/sessions URL, the curly brace is encoded to `%7D` so removing this from the end of the publishable key should work (as long as the publishable key is the correct counterpart to the secret key you're using server side).

Comment: Yes! That was it. You have saved me. Just for your information, it was a misspelling in our Ansible script that did a `{{ stripe_key }}}` . Now that I think of it, I wonder how it ever compiled.